# c++ call and wait for external program and get result

Tags: c++, process

I am using c++, qt 5 and VS2012 for my project. For controlling an external device, I have to use an external static library.
The library seems to be very bad, because program compilation success depends on the position of the "#include extlib.h" and even when compilation works, my program is influenced unpredictably.
Using the external lib only works fine, when the code for the external device is in a seperate program. My workaround idea:
Call device controll program from my main project, wait unit execution is complete and receive the result value (double).

How can I start an external program from my c++ main program, wait until execution of external program is complete and receive a result value (double) in my main program?

Comment: Do you want it synchronous (bad idea in the main thread of a UI application) or asynchronous (strongly preferred in an UI application)? QProcess::execute() for the former, QProcess instance for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You could exec() it from your program into a thread, then this thread could wait for the result being given by [interprocess communication](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/interprocess.html)